# Изменение параметров объекта в списке List set JAVA

Tags: java, list

Ребята, я начинающий в программировании. Выбрал Java. По мере изучения учебников, ставлю собой небольшую задачу (на базе полученных знаний) и придумываю всякие программы. Вот например программа (очень простая) , но ломаю голову уже который час!

Программа спрашивает пользователя какую марку машины он хочет добавить в автопарк?

Пользователь (по номеру) вводит ее и так для всех параметров хочу сделать.

Класс Cars , в конструкторе 3 параметра.

Создал ArrayList и каждый раз (при добавлении машины в автопарк) добавляется в List новый объект класса Cars.

Так вот все бы хорошо, но как изменить значение параметра объекта в ArrayList!?

```
//Создание массиваArrayList из объекта Cars
    ArrayList UnitCar = new ArrayList();
    //UnitCar.add(new Cars("Honda", "Hatchback", 150));          
    //Заполнение массива              
    //Заполнение ArrayList пользователем:
    while(true){
        //Создание сканнера, считывающего нажатие:
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Добавление объекта в ArrayList 
        UnitCar.add(new Cars(null, null, 0));
        System.out.println("Выберете марку автомобиля:");
        System.out.println("1: Honda, 2: Subaru, 3: Ford, 4: Chevrolet, 5: Nissan, 0: завершение программы ");

        //Создание массива типа int, в котром будут хранится 3 параметра автомобиля
        //Марка, тип кузова, максимальная скорость.
        int ChooiseCar[] = new int[2];

        //Ввод пользователем
        ChooiseCar[0] = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Выберете тип кузова:");
        System.out.println("1: Седан, 2: Хэтчбэк, 3: Универсал, 4: Кроссовер");

        ChooiseCar[1] = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Выберете макимальную скорость (км/ч):");

        ChooiseCar[2] = sc.nextInt();

        //Создание объектов, по параметрам введденными пользоваталем:
        //Марка автомобиля
        if (ChooiseCar[0] == 1)
        {
            **UnitCar.set(0("Honda", null, 0));**

        }
```

*UPDATE:*

Все поправил, все работает, объект настраивается пользователем как надо (все выводит как настроено) , но я опять-таки не могу добавить свой объект в ArrayList , как правильно это сделать?

```
System.out.println("Ваш первый автомобиль:");
           System.out.println("Марка: " + machine.getBrand());
           System.out.println("Кузов: " + machine.getType());
           System.out.println("Максимальная скорость: " + machine.getMaxSpeed() + " к/ч");
           break;

           **CarList.add(machine(null, null, 0));**
//Знаю, что здесь должны быть методы getX , null'ы для проверки ввел, и все-равно, никак параметры не настроить...
```

UPDATE:

Господи все дело было в том, что добавление объекта в ArrayList было после break основного цикла :-) извините за идиотские вопросы :_)

Comment: Проблема в самом низу (UnitCar.set(0("Honda", null, 0));)

Comment: Вам необходимо изменить например марку в уже существующем (добавленном в List ) авто ?

Comment: если да то проще всего в вашем коде перенести добавление в List ниже чем запрос данных пользователя, и вносить авто с уже известными параметрами.

Comment: Именно так, мне надо изменить поле Brand типа String, это первый параметр в конструкторе класса Cars. При выполнении программы создается объект типа Car (с null параметрами) и добавляется в list.В ходе программы пользователь меняет параметры объекта!

Comment: проще всего в Вашем коде перенести добавление в List ниже чем запрос данных пользователя, и вносить авто с уже известными параметрами.   Либо  UnitCar.get(index).setBrand(BrandNameStr);

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но проще не хочется, хочется научится менять значения так, как я изначально планировал :-)

Comment: В Вашем классе Cars должны быть методы get/set вида getBrand() setBrand(String brand). И еще несколько моментов по коду: 1 Имя класса в единственном числе  2 Имена переменных (полей) с маленькой буквы  Т.Е. класс Car и имя List-а - unitCars

Comment: Спасибо, так я и подозревал, что getters setters тут необходимы. Т.е. при изменении объекта в List просто вызывается метод setBrand?)

Comment: Когда вы добавляете Car в list то он там уже есть, и вам в нем необходимо заменить внутреннее поле, для этого Объект Car надо получить, что и делает метод .get(). Еще есть 2й более неправильный вариант - создавть новый объект и заменить им существующий, но это плохое решение, но если что то есть перегруженый метод .set(int,Object)

Comment: Спасибо большое, что отвечаешь на мои вопросы- но у меня взрывается мозг...

Comment: Не дописал свой комментарий (нажал слуайно ентер)-
Вот смотри- у меня есть класс Car

Но ведь я постоянно создаю новые объекты и добавляются они в List с null параметрами

Так почему нельзя менять параметры объектов в list без setters'ов?!

Я думал у меня просто синтаксически не получается это сделать (последняя строчка кода)

Comment: @ Владимир Водов тебе просто повезло что на меня попал, я помню как сам начинал и было вопросов слишком много. Смотри, с точки зрения Инкапсуляции ты не должен менять параметры напрямую, то-есть поля должны быть приватными. И чтоб поменять значения приватного поля необходимо иметь геттер / сеттер. А последняя строка кода это не на java а скорее всего на чем то типа питона или еще чего

Comment: Я не зазнаюсь, но когда я стану таким же гуру как-ты сейчас (хотя ты всегда будешь опережать, ибо нет предела совершенству), я тоже буду постоянно отвечать на вопросы, так как сам понимаю всю сложность этой темы :-)

Так это с точки зрения инкапсуляции, но у меня ничего нет private, все public и static.

Comment: Просто у меня все разбито в пакете на классы (учусь так чтобы не кодить в одном классе) , значит надо следовать правилам инкапсуляции и все получится в моем примере?

Comment: тогда тебе необходимо понять в чем смысл инкапсуляции и модификаторов статики. static модификатор говорит что то что им помечено является общим для всех объектов этого класса. Инкапсуляция (ограничение доступности ) - почитай в инете

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать данный раздел внимательнее. Жаль плюс поставить нельзя тебе никак, или можно?)

Comment: это не критично, не запаривайся. Почитай про инкапсуляцию, модификаторы статичности, и посмотри про основные принципы ООП (Наследование Икапсуляция, Полиморфизм)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом set(int index, Cars newVal); index - можно получить методом indexOf(Cars value);
Для того чтобы это работало вам необходимо в вашем классе Cars переопределить метод equals.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ :-)

У  настроил сеттеры и геттеры, теперь при добавлении от пользователя объект класса Car настраивается замечательно.

НО! 

Опять при добавлении в ранее инициализированный ArrayList CarList

Не могу добавить в него объект.

Пишу CarList.add(machine(getBrand, getType, getMaxSpeed)); и все равно unreachable statement... проблема в том, что гугля ArrayList там добавляются просто строки в переменные и так далее (в примерах) но нигде не нашел пример добавление объекта в ArrayList помогите пожалуйста!